# Singular or plural usage for 'face' in the sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> 1. **We** should wash our **face** with clean water.
> 2. **We** should wash our **faces** with clean water.

Which is more natural, 'face' or 'faces'?

Does the plural subject 'we' require a plural noun in the object?

Comment: If you have a picture of your family and yourself is there. Do you say that "our pictures"? It's one face that we share together. Plural subject doesnt always followed by a plural noun as an object

Comment: @user178049 - Yes, but we do share one picture.  We don't share one face.

Comment: @stangdon sure, sharing face doesnt make sense here. But the concept is same right?

Comment: @user178049: no, the concept is the exact opposite. In my opinion "faces" is almost always the right choice here.

Comment: In some languages you'd definitely use the singular.  Having been *explicitly told* this when I learned French (forty years ago), I'd say that most English-speakers use and expect the plural, with perhaps an exception for parts of a uniform: _We wear our badge on our right shoulder(s)._

Comment: Except for [kings, queens and popes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we), of course.

Comment: Hi, @learner. I've noticed that in all of your questions, you have never "accepted" any of the answers. Are you aware of that functionality on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 13):

If *each individual [item]* implied by a plural subject *has only one of* something (each of us has one *face*, in OP's example), we tend to extend the plurality of the subject *(**we**)* to the object *(**faces**)*. Thus:

> 1: *We can hold our **heads** up* [- 720 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20can%20hold%20our%20head%20up%22#tbm=bks&q=%22we%20can%20hold%20our%20heads%20up%22)
>    2: *We can hold our **head** up* [- 121 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20can%20hold%20our%20head%20up%22)

But if you look at some of the results there, I'm sure you'll find that the second (singular) set will have more contexts where we're all taking pride *exactly in the same thing* (as opposed to each of us being proud of *our specific version* of whatever it is).

So in OP's specific example, most people in most contexts would use plural ***faces***. But if preceding text had focused on "the face" in a more "generic, archetypal" way (for example, *A stranger's face is usually the first thing we look at when we meet them*), it wouldn't be unreasonable for the writer to continue with the singular when recommending that everyone should wash their face properly.

---

There's one additional point to consider in contexts like OP's. Sometimes (especially when addressing *children*), we use ***we*** when we really mean ***you*** (singular or plural, we do it in both contexts). Thus:

> (Teacher to lazy pupil)
>    3: *We didn't do our homework, did we?*
>
> (Dentist examining new client's mouth)
>    4: *We haven't been using our dental floss, have we?*

That interpretation (***we*** means ***you***, and *doesn't* include the speaker) isn't always possible. But it certainly *could* apply in OP's context, so bearing in mind this would represent a very ***condescending*** style of address, that might be one more reason to use the plural in that exact context.

Comment: I think this is worth noting: In your examples of "we" meaning "you", both "homework" and "floss" are mass nouns. That may be trickier when it's a noun like "face" that needs to be clearly singular or plural.

Comment: @recognizer: I don't think the plurality of the object nouns in my examples has any relevance to the point being made. I could just as well have illustrated using *We're just being lazy* or similar.

Comment: In many decades of speaking this language, the extension of plurality has never occurred to me until I read the above. Of course, I _said_ things like "wash our face," but never paid it any mind. But the OP's first example is an error in number, aye?

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Well,... ***No!*** Is my answer text really that unclear? The whole *point* of it was to convey that both versions are "valid". And it's possible to imagine contexts where singular might actually be the *preferred* form for OP's exact text. As per the example I tried to give above, where the preceding talk may have focused on ***the face*** as some kind of "disembodied archetypal face" - making it seem perfectly natural to refer to it in the singular even if there must be at least *two* faces (that of the speaker *and* his potentially singular audience).

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I wouldn't say it was an error, just that it is applying 'we' to a set of individuals. When we're alone, we each wash only our own face. That seems (slightly) less wrong...

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, F⚡︎F... The more I consider this, the more subtle a point it becomes. Your answer isn't unclear at all, but it doesn't address the disagreement in number explicitly. A stolid and dogmatic prescriptivist would call it an error in number, wouldn't she? I can see Mrs. Blashfield's florid cheeks before me even now, as she fills the air with chalk dust from her furiously deployed eraser.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I don't really know much about "stolid and dogmatic prescriptivists". So far as I recall, my English teachers only cared that we should read quality texts, be able to spell, and such - I can't imagine any of them would have wasted time on explicitly telling us to respect pettifogging "pseudo-rules" like this. It all smacks of the AmE habit of insisting that words like *family* or *company* must always be coupled to a singular noun (another one of those superficially logical but actually meaningless "rules" that *constrain* language instead of *explaining* it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you misunderstand me. I agree wholeheartedly that "rules" like this are pettifoggery. You were evidently more fortunate than I, or even me, because my teachers, in particular The Blashfield, would have taken "stolid and dogmatic prescriptivist" as a compliment, and would have dressed any paper that contained _We should wash our face_ in scarlet letters. I was only trying to point out a corollary to what you just wrote: that the psuedo-rule (for which there must be another word which I can't access) is probably the reason for the OP's question.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: (I think I may have asked before, but forgotten the answer. :) Are you *American*, perchance? My perception is that *on average* Americans get formally "taught" much more about "correct use of English" than Brits. Which I put down to the historically higher proportion of non-native Anglophones in the US (leading to the perception that if you want to get on in life, you have to know every last detail of prescriptive Victorian grammar). Perhaps it'll go that way in the UK soon, since I think *we* now have a higher proportion of immigrants than the US).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aye. Like many Americanos I can speak several almost mutually unintelligible dialects, one our version of RP (once but no longer received at prep and university) and the other a regional or even more narrowly localized patois. As with many in my generation, English was inflicted upon me by a succession of tight-sphinctered martinets who wielded _Descriptive English Grammar_ like a cudgel, laying waste anything living in the language.

Comment: @P. E. Dant:  In 1921 [H. L. Mencken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._L._Mencken) could write [English spelling is very much more conservative than American](http://www.bartleby.com/185/36.html) (admittedly, specifically in re loan-words). But I think things have changed a lot in a century. Turning to *real* (spoken) language, I often notice Americans retaining the original pronunciation of things like ***herbs*** and ***Porche*** which we Anglicized long ago over here. (Then there's ***filet*** (steak), which you guys still both spell *and* pronounce like cheese-eating surrender monkeys! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The struggle between posh talk and pleb in Chicago over the name of a certain baked delicacy began several decades ago and is still undecided. We heard kɹwɑˈsɑ̃, then we heard 'krɔɪzənt, and finally the splicing is complete and I often hear krɔɪˈsɑ̃. Both registers are served!

Answer (score 9):

In this case, I'd say you need the plural "faces". As, presumably, we each have our own face, you are talking about many faces here.

But it isn't true that a plural subject requires a plural object. Many people could be acting on one thing. For example, "We should keep our neighborhood clean." There could be many people all living in one neighborhood. Plural subject, singular object. One person could be acting on many things. "I should wash my hands with clean water." One person but he has two hands. Singular subject, plural object.

Comment: And what about the song? This is the way we wash our face...

Comment: Saying our faces is like we were multiface

Comment: @V.V.: The only song that comes to mind for me is *This is the way we pick our nose, pick our nose, pick our nose:/ This is the way we pick our nose, so early in the morning*. That's riffing off ***Here we go round the mulberry bush***, so it *has* to be singular to maintain scansion.

Answer (score 0):

From the position of descriptive grammar, the usage that is most common in your dialect is more 'natural'.

From a technical perspective, the confusion arises due to a lost reference for possession.

To clarify, think of a family who owns one car-

We should all wash our car.

A family that owns several cars-

We should all (every one of us) wash our cars.

A family where each member owns a car-

We should all (each one of us) wash our (own) car.

A family where each member owns several cars-

We should all wash our cars.

Confusion arises because the last form is a grammatically correct expression. At the same time, unlike a car, it is implicitly understood that each one of us has only one face.

Read the following three sentences to see if you can understand how the singular 'face' makes sense when possession is understood clearly.

We should all wash a face with clean water.

We should all wash our own face with clean water.

We should all wash our face with clean water.

Notice how 'own' specifies what is implicitly understood, each one of us owns just one face.